# Error installing nvidia graphics driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, cuda

I freshly installed Ubuntu18.04 and was trying to install new nvidia drivers to install cuda but can't get rid of this error.
Stack Trace:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-390:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-390:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
582 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 236531 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-compute-390_390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-390_390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd', which is different from other instances of package libnvidia-compute-390:i386
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-390_390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

On trying @jordan 's answer I get the following error:

```
 lambda-stack-cuda : Depends: nvidia-cuda-toolkit but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-driver-390 but it is not going to be installed
 libcudnn-dev : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (= 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-pycuda : Depends: nvidia-cuda-toolkit but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pycuda : Depends: nvidia-cuda-toolkit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling secure boot and installing bumblebee were the things which were needed to make the system work.
For more details refer [this](https://medium.com/@agathver/nvidia-gpu-optimus-prime-and-ubuntu-18-04-woes-f52e7f850f3d).

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this myself, I was able to fix it by doing:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
reboot
```

Comment: Check the edited question.